# StatusStripLabel Events for image and text independently

Tags: c#

I Have a StatusStripLabel on which Text and Image has been placed.
Now i want to call indenpendent event for both Text and Image..
Like On Text Click..
It should be Text_Click..
On Image Click
It Should be Image_Click..

The above mentioned scenario in Possible or NOT ??????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhat possible... You can test the location of the `MouseUp` event's `MouseEventArgs` against the bounds of the image used in the `ToolStripStatusLabel`.

```
private void statusLabel_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ToolStripStatusLabel statusLabel = (ToolStripStatusLabel)sender;
    GraphicsUnit unit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;

    if (statusLabel.Image.GetBounds(ref unit).Contains(e.Location))
        MessageBox.Show("Clicked on image.");
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Clicked on text.");
}
```

There are a few pre-conditions though: `ToolStripStatusLabel.TextImageRelation` must be set to `TextImageRelation.ImageBeforeText` and `ToolStripStatusLabel.ImageScaling` must be set to `ToolStripItemImageScaling.None`. Otherwise you'll have to add some more logic.

Comment: Thank you Sir..  But what if i Want to perform on Click Event Rather than MouseUp

Comment: @Aditya The `Click` event does not deliver the pixel location of the click with its `EventArgs`. The `MouseUp` event, however, does. I see no other solution. But if you like you can derive from `ToolStripStatusLabel` and implement two new events, `ImageClick` and `LabelClick`, which will be fired in the above `MouseUp` handler.